# Move files in subdirectories in python

Tags: python, shutil

I have one big folder in which my python script resides, and it has about 100 subfolders. I'm trying to find every subfolder that contains less than 5 files, and move those files to the subfolder called "misc". Here is what I have tried so far:

```py
import os
import os.path
import shutil

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
misc = 'misc'

for dir,subdir,files in os.walk(path):
    if len(files) < 5:
        for x in files:
            shutil.move(x, os.path.join(path, misc, x))
```

I get an error `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'pic1.jpg' -> 'C:/Users/UCD/Desktop/Folder/misc\\pic1.jpg`

As far as I can tell, it's looking for the file in the "misc" folder, but I don't know why.

I think the problem is with the `shutil.move` line, because if I replace it with `print(x)`, it prints out the correct files (i.e. only prints out the files from the folders that contain less than 5), but I can't get them to move.

Comment: resolve x you will get the output,x must be the absolute path of the file not the file name

Comment: I'm not sure what any of that means @Myjab